# Open Modal (popover) with iframe when mousover cell in tabualtor

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popover, tabulator

I have a table of data and when a user hovers over a certain cell I would like to open and modal and display an iframe within the modal. I have managed to call a function from the hover event but im lost as how to open a popover as all popovers appear to rely on class id's , when i try this I get nothing I assume thats because the class is assigned to the table.

I have this as my colulnm def

```
{title:"img/pressure2.png",field:"pi1",width:30,formatter:"html",titleFormatter:"image",headerSort:false,align:"center", 
               cellMouseOver:function(e, row){ not sure what goes here}
```

Ideally I want to over a popover with the following

```
popover({
            content: function() {
                return '<div style="width: 440px; height=220px"><iframe src="../../pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=' + id + '&pi=pi1" width=440 height=220></iframe></div>';
            },
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'left',
            html: true,
```

I have tried launching a function, this works and I can pass the gameid but I cant seem to find a way to launch the popover, I also tried putting the modal code in the callback function but again no luck.

Comment: Working demo please

Comment: Hi dota2pro
This is a work in progress and I'll tidy the code up once im happy with it
https://soccerscanner.net/new/livescore.html

So when the mouse is placed over the pressure, at the moment it throws up undefinded, what I want to do is grab the matchid from the row and bring up a modal to display the following page in an iframe
https://soccerscanner.net/pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=100EF9BF&pi=pi1

Comment: I meant can you create your issue that needs to be addressed in a Jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikehobson/pen/vYBmZWb?editors=1111, its doesnt seem to render well in my pen for some reason but all im after is a way to launch a popover when the mouse goes over pi1